# Searching a text value in multiple excel files and copying below cell value to master file

Tags: vba, excel

I was working with a code to extract data from multiple excel files in a folder from muliple cells and paste the extracted values to a master file. For example Name was in cell A9, Phone in cell B6 etc.

But now there was change in raw data recived and cell places are changed dynamically. The only thing same through which i can find those values is that through searching by text, if I have to find "Name" I need the code to first find text "Name" and the copy the value below the found cell. That is if "Name" found in cell "A10" then I need the code to copy value "A11", same way find text "Phone" and if text found in cell "B23" copy value of "B24" and so on.

```
Sub Consolidate()

Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
Dim originsheet As Worksheet
Dim destsheet As Worksheet
Dim ResultRow As Long
Dim Fname As String
Dim RngDest As Range



Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Extractdata")
Set RngDest = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                   .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xlsx")

'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name

    If Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

        Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
        Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Table 1")

        With RngDest
            .Cells(1).Value = originsheet.Range("A3").Value
            .Cells(2).Value = originsheet.Range("C21").Value
            .Cells(3).Value = originsheet.Range("E21").Value
            .Cells(4).Value = originsheet.Range("A23").Value
            .Cells(5).Value = originsheet.Range("A31").Value
        End With

        wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
        Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

    Fname = Dir()     'get next file
Loop
End Sub
```

Kindly help me in making the changes with the below code as i am getting it right to work.

[image: I need the values highlighted in yellow]

All the values highlighted in yellow needs to be copied.
Only thing common is the words or texts above the highlighted cells as range of cells changes as per workbooks.

Comment: You can use the worksheet functions vlooup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx

Comment: I am not sure how to add the vlookup function with it while searching for cells which can be in any rows or column.

Comment: can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: Please check the screenshot of the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Find()` and `.Offset()` methods:

```
With RngDest
        .Cells(1).Value = originsheet.Cells.Find("NAME").Offset(1, 0).Value
        .Cells(2).Value = originsheet.Cells.Find("DATE").Offset(1, 0).Value
        .Cells(3).Value = originsheet.Cells.Find("PLACE").Offset(1, 0).Value
        '// etc ...
End With
```

Comment: It worked great! Also if I want to add the name of each files in corresponding cell with the respective data, what else i need to add in the code to give me the names of files.